# How to move apps

Tags: insufficient-memory, app2sd

How can I have LG e-612 running on jelly bean. Without apps it gives proper performance. When I'm trying to install apps from play store they get installed in internal memory. Phone is slow and sluggish. So I just want to move apps to external memory or micro sd card. LG customer care  say you can not move. So I checked many forums and tutorials but maximum are about rooting android none of them clears me. So how can I move apps to external memory or micro sd card?

Comment: They gave you the answer. You can't.

Comment: @SarpSTA speaking Einstein: that's relative. From the POV of LG Service, they don't want you to (or they had provided means). There are still ways to accomplish that, but they will most certainly require root. // DENTIST: I've just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. Please check with [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an app to your SD Card will use memory even on your phone so I think this doesn't help your situation really (At least that what I experienced) but give it a try without root , Their should be a button located on the app properties "Move to SD Card" . Like I say this will NOT move them from the system but its worth a shot I suppose .Every phone is different

Comment: We're talking LG here. Starting with Android 4.x, they've removed that button; if it were there, they hadn't said "you can't" – and OP certainly had found that button already ;)

Answer (score -2):

these the simple  first select on app then mark all the apps and there options like move your app to sd card then click on it .am talking about LG e612

Comment: Sorry, could you use proper English? I'm having difficulty to understand this answer. Where do you select the app? How to mark all apps? Where's the option to move to SD?